# How can I make this function work on load?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I tried to make this function work when `componentDidMount` 
but it didn't work.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
        $('body').addClass('modal-active');
    });

    $('#modal-container').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('out');
        $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
    });

    console.log("hi");
}
```

Comment: Which function? You're attaching events.

Comment: Would you mind describing the expected behavior and what you are you seeing instead? Also, please share the JSX in question.

Comment: There is no need to make `componentDidMount` into a class field arrow function. You can write `componentDidMount() { ... }`. May I ask why you are mixing React and jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanna change class of element. You dont need use componentDidMount(). So i added an example below.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {addClass: false}
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({addClass: !this.state.addClass});
  }
  render() {
    let boxClass = ["box"];
    if(this.state.addClass) {
      boxClass.push('green');
    }
    return(
        <div className={boxClass.join(' ')} onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>{this.state.addClass ? "Remove a class" : "Add a class (click the box)"}<br />Read the tutorial <a href="http://www.automationfuel.com" target="_blank">here</a>.</div>       
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box.green {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```